# syslog-ng の flush_lines　オプションが効かない

Tags: linux

ubuntu14.04 に syslog-ng 3.5.3をインストールしました。

syslog-ngによるシステム負荷の削減のためflush_linesオプションでまとめてログを保存することを考えています。
syslon-ngのインストールには成功し、動作もしています。

tail -f /var/log/messages でログを表示させて動作確認しています。

グローバルオプションに flush_lines(2)を追加して試したのですが、設定前と同じく即座にログが表示されてしまいます。

どなたかflush_linesを適切に設定し、ログ出力をまとめて実施する設定を教えてください。

実際に使用している設定は以下です。

```
@version: 3.5
@include "scl.conf"
@include "`scl-root`/system/tty10.conf"

# Syslog-ng configuration file, compatible with default Debian syslogd
# installation.

# First, set some global options.
options { chain_hostnames(off); flush_lines(2); use_dns(no); use_fqdn(no);
      owner("root"); group("adm"); perm(0640); stats_freq(0);
      bad_hostname("^gconfd$");
};

########################
# Sources
########################
# This is the default behavior of sysklogd package
# Logs may come from unix stream, but not from another machine.
#
source s_src {
       system();
       internal();
};

# If you wish to get logs from remote machine you should uncomment
# this and comment the above source line.
#
#source s_net { tcp(ip(127.0.0.1) port(1000)); };

########################
# Destinations
########################
# First some standard logfile
#
destination d_auth { file("/var/log/auth.log"); };
destination d_cron { file("/var/log/cron.log"); };
destination d_daemon { file("/var/log/daemon.log"); };
destination d_kern { file("/var/log/kern.log"); };
destination d_lpr { file("/var/log/lpr.log"); };
destination d_mail { file("/var/log/mail.log"); };
destination d_syslog { file("/var/log/syslog"); };
destination d_user { file("/var/log/user.log"); };
destination d_uucp { file("/var/log/uucp.log"); };

# This files are the log come from the mail subsystem.
#
destination d_mailinfo { file("/var/log/mail.info"); };
destination d_mailwarn { file("/var/log/mail.warn"); };
destination d_mailerr { file("/var/log/mail.err"); };

# Logging for INN news system
#
destination d_newscrit { file("/var/log/news/news.crit"); };
destination d_newserr { file("/var/log/news/news.err"); };
destination d_newsnotice { file("/var/log/news/news.notice"); };

# Some `catch-all' logfiles.
#
destination d_debug { file("/var/log/debug"); };
destination d_error { file("/var/log/error"); };
destination d_messages { file("/var/log/messages"); };

# The root's console.
#
destination d_console { usertty("root"); };

# Virtual console.
#
destination d_console_all { file(`tty10`); };

# The named pipe /dev/xconsole is for the nsole' utility.  To use it,
# you must invoke nsole' with the -file' option:
#
#    $ xconsole -file /dev/xconsole [...]
#
destination d_xconsole { pipe("/dev/xconsole"); };

# Send the messages to an other host
#
#destination d_net { tcp("127.0.0.1" port(1000) log_fifo_size(1000)); };

# Debian only
destination d_ppp { file("/var/log/ppp.log"); };

########################
# Filters
########################
# Here's come the filter options. With this rules, we can set which 
# message go where.

filter f_dbg { level(debug); };
filter f_info { level(info); };
filter f_notice { level(notice); };
filter f_warn { level(warn); };
filter f_err { level(err); };
filter f_crit { level(crit .. emerg); };

filter f_debug { level(debug) and not facility(auth, authpriv, news, mail); };
filter f_error { level(err .. emerg) ; };
filter f_messages { level(info,notice,warn) and 
                    not facility(auth,authpriv,cron,daemon,mail,news); };

filter f_auth { facility(auth, authpriv) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_cron { facility(cron) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_daemon { facility(daemon) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_kern { facility(kern) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_lpr { facility(lpr) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_local { facility(local0, local1, local3, local4, local5,
                        local6, local7) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_mail { facility(mail) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_news { facility(news) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_syslog3 { not facility(auth, authpriv, mail) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_user { facility(user) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_uucp { facility(uucp) and not filter(f_debug); };

filter f_cnews { level(notice, err, crit) and facility(news); };
filter f_cother { level(debug, info, notice, warn) or facility(daemon, mail); };

filter f_ppp { facility(local2) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_console { level(warn .. emerg); };

########################
# Log paths
########################
log { source(s_src); filter(f_auth); destination(d_auth); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_cron); destination(d_cron); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_daemon); destination(d_daemon); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_kern); destination(d_kern); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_lpr); destination(d_lpr); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_syslog3); destination(d_syslog); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_user); destination(d_user); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_uucp); destination(d_uucp); };

log { source(s_src); filter(f_mail); destination(d_mail); };
#log { source(s_src); filter(f_mail); filter(f_info); destination(d_mailinfo); };
#log { source(s_src); filter(f_mail); filter(f_warn); destination(d_mailwarn); };
#log { source(s_src); filter(f_mail); filter(f_err); destination(d_mailerr); };

log { source(s_src); filter(f_news); filter(f_crit); destination(d_newscrit); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_news); filter(f_err); destination(d_newserr); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_news); filter(f_notice); destination(d_newsnotice); };
#log { source(s_src); filter(f_cnews); destination(d_console_all); };
#log { source(s_src); filter(f_cother); destination(d_console_all); };

#log { source(s_src); filter(f_ppp); destination(d_ppp); };

log { source(s_src); filter(f_debug); destination(d_debug); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_error); destination(d_error); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_messages); destination(d_messages); };

log { source(s_src); filter(f_console); destination(d_console_all);
                    destination(d_xconsole); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_crit); destination(d_console); };

# All messages send to a remote site
#
#log { source(s_src); destination(d_net); };

###
# Include all config files in /etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/
###
@include "/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/*.conf"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

syslog-ng 3.5.6 のソースコードを入手して調べてみた所、ある条件判定に不足がある様です。
具体的には、`syslog-ng-3.5.6/lib/logwriter.c` の `log_writer_flush()` 関数です。

```c
gboolean
log_writer_flush(LogWriter *self, LogWriterFlushMode flush_mode)
{
                       :

  if (flush_mode >= LW_FLUSH_BUFFER || count == 0)
  {
    if (log_proto_client_flush(proto) == LPS_ERROR)
      return FALSE;
  }
```

この `log_proto_client_flush()` 関数がログファイルへの書き込みを行っているのですが、直前の条件判定が不十分なのではないか、という事です。
実際には syslog プロセスのメッセージバッファの大きさ(行単位)と `flush_lines` の設定値を比較する処理が必要だと思われるのですが、`log_proto_client_flush()` 関数内でもその判定は行われていません。そこで、条件式の部分を以下の様に書き換えます。

```c
LogProtoFileWriter *w = (LogProtoFileWriter *)proto;
if ( (w->buf_count >= w->buf_size) && (flush_mode >= LW_FLUSH_BUFFER || count == 0) )
  {
    if (log_proto_client_flush(proto) == LPS_ERROR)
      return FALSE;
  }
```

`w->buf_count` がメッセージバッファの行数に当たります(実際には一行毎の構造体配列のサイズ)。`w->buf_size` は `flush_lines` の設定値です。

ただ、`LogProtoFileWriter` 型(構造体)の定義が別のファイル(`syslog-ng-3.5.6/modules/affile/logproto-file-writer.c`)で行われています。ヘッダファイルではないファイルを `include` するのも何ですので、定義部分だけを `logwriter.c` ファイルにコピーします。

```c
typedef struct _LogProtoFileWriter
{
  LogProtoClient super;
  guchar *partial;
  gsize partial_len, partial_pos;
  gint buf_size;
  gint buf_count;
  gint fd;
  gint sum_len;
  gboolean fsync;
  struct iovec buffer[0];
} LogProtoFileWriter;
```

変更後、コンパイル・リンクして syslog-ng を動作させると `flush_lines` が有効になりました。動作環境は Ubuntu Linux 15.04 です。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
当方でも試してみたいと思います。
ところで・・・本件は既知のバグなのでしょうか？
syslog-ng自体はそこそこ長い間使われているので、未だにこんなところにバグがあるのが不思議です・・。
syncからflush_linesへの置き換え時などに発生したバグなのでしょうか。
経緯をご存知の方がいらしたら教えてください。

Comment: 私個人の勝手な憶測ですが、syslog-ng のモジュール化が進められた段階で例の条件判定が抜け落ちたのではないかと(sql モジュールの方には判定処理があります)…。ところで、コメントだけでは投稿の順位が上がりませんので、質問欄の方に追記した方が良いかと思います。